# IIS 10.0 - AllowAnonymous for one application folder (Controller doesn't work)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

My ASP.NET web application is using a `Windows Authentication` and I just want to enable `anonymous` users to be able to enter one folder (let's call it `"XYZ"`).
So in the `XYZ` I have a web config created by the IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Inside the `XYZ` I have a HTML page, and entering the URL like:

```
www.site.com/XYZ/htmlPage.html
```

It is opening without asking about permissions and everything is good.
But when I do the same with my controller action (controller is inside the `XYZ` of couse), I'm getting the `401` error code.

Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Test content");
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "XYZRoute",
            url: "XYZ/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

No idea where I'm making a mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your main web.config inside `<configuration>` section:

```
<location path="XYZ">
   <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

And you can delete remove web config inside `XYZ` folder